# Obfuscated code throws error in a Greasemonkey Script

Tags: php, javascript, greasemonkey, obfuscation

I have a Greasemonkey script that I want to be obfuscated. I was wondering what goes wrong with the available ["Packer" Javascript obfuscator](http://code.google.com/p/base2/source/browse/trunk/src/apps/packer#packer%253Fstate%253Dclosed).

It compresses the script fine but after installation, the script doesn't work. Is there any PHP Class that would obfuscate/pack GM scripts and retain functionality? Or how do I go about doing this?

Error:

```
Timestamp: 01-05-2013 13:11:35
Error: missing ; before statement
Source File: file://file_path
Line: 1
```

Script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Test
// @namespace      http://*
// @description    Test
// @require         http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var SomeVar = "Something";
GM_setValue("foo","bar");
var AnotherVar = GM_getValue("foo");
alert(AnotherVar);
```

Packed Script:

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=String;if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[c]=k[c]||c;k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('0 3="4";5("1","6");0 2=7("1");8(2);',9,9,'var|foo|AnotherVar|SomeVar|Something|GM_setValue|bar|GM_getValue|alert'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Comment: Just going to throw it out there - you know those packers won't stop a mildly-determined person from viewing the code, right?

Comment: Any error codes in the console?

Comment: If something does not work, and you decide to ask for help, then mention what problems you are facing (error messages, relevant system information, and do on).

Comment: I understand that it won't stop determined person from viewing the code, but it still is *some* level of security, and at least makes it harder for them to decipher.
(@ Others: Error obtained didn't seem significant, syntax error, but added it anyway)

Comment: Packer just makes me curious to see the code. It take 1 second to copy to the console and add console.log.

Comment: Related question: [Protect Greasemonkey scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3284680/331508)

Comment: I know the related question Brock, however that packer is what did not work, and script compiler is just making it a zip, (.xpi = zip archive). I don't want that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, your "Packed Script" works fine on my test page. You did **keep the [Metadata block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block) as-is**, right?

Also, you should add:

```
// @grant GM_setValue
// @grant GM_getValue
```

to the metadata block to (1) avoid jQuery (and other) conflicts and (2) ensure that those `GM_` functions are always switched on.

---

Your problem is one or more of:

1. You tried to pack or obfuscate the Metadata block.  **You cannot do this**; the Greasemonkey add-on uses this precise, clear-text format to determine how to handle a given script.
2. A conflict with a specific page. (The `@grant` settings, should fix that).
3. Something in your code that you are not showing us.
4. An edit error, installation error, or "confused" instance of Firefox.

   1. Uninstall the script.
   2. Completely shutdown Firefox, make sure all FF tasks have stopped.
   3. Restart FF and reinstall the script.
   4. Follow [the troubleshooting tips starting at "Script Errors"](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Troubleshooting_%28Users%29#Script_Errors), on down.
   5. See, also, [Troubleshooting (Script Authors)](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Troubleshooting_%28Script_Authors%29)