# HTML5 Protection - Polymorphic behavior

Tags: html

I'm not looking for javascript code that changes itself. What I'm looking for is a HTML5 obfuscator that spits out different versions of the same source code. The general idea is to be able to deliver a different code version per user request.

Every solution that I've tried outputs the same obfuscated javascript. The best I could find only changed the variables and function names, but not the code structure.

Comment: Seems similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862470/javascript-library-to-obfuscate-or-not-to-obfuscate-that-is-the-question

Comment: You do realize that just because the code changes with every request, it is not any harder to un-obfuscate? All a user would have to do is save you code and reverse engineer that. They now have a static non changing code example.

Comment: It depends on what is your goal. I think it makes sense if you're just trying to stop attack automation e.g. the attack expects the target code to have some form, function name, or whatever, and basically the code changing per each request will require a more sophisticated attack and perhaps frustrate the attacker. If on the other hand you are just trying to hide what you are doing, then I agree with you. You make sense of one version, you make sense of them all.