# Javascript Obfuscator to run locally which each compile

Tags: javascript, asp.net, obfuscation

I want a free command line application or Java application that I can run on one of my JavaScript files and obfuscate it. I prefer to run it when I compile my website in visual studio locally, but it can be a software that runs locally and I will run it manually.

I want a strong obfuscator that even when reversed engineer, it will be very difficult to understand the code. My project was built with ASP.net and C# if that matters for the answer. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot protect your code, really.  If it's as valuable as you think it is, then it's worth somebody's while to reverse-engineer it, so you might as well plan on it happening.  (However "obfuscation" for purposes of code size reduction is worth the effort.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend google closure compiler: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home to minify your JavaScript. For maximum "obfuscation", write your code so you can utilize the "advanced" optimization. You could also add all your scripts and compile them into one big chunk of minified code.

This does not make it impossible to reverse-engineer, not even difficult for the professional programmer, but it will most likely be enough trouble for most people to "steal" it, unless it’s a goldmine you are hiding.

Now, why you would want to "obfuscate" your code, and what it might be worth in your case is another debate...

Here are some interesting takes on the subject:
[Is using an obfuscator enough to secure my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399/is-using-an-obfuscator-enough-to-secure-my-javascript-code)